# Subquery retorna mais de um resultado

Tags: sql, case, cte, union-all

Boa tarde! Tenho a seguinte query que contabiliza o total de inscritos por curso. Quero buscar a maior quantidade de inscrito conforme código:

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT IDPS, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CURSOS
WHERE IDAREAINTERESSE = 60) AS DIREITO, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CURSOS
WHERE IDAREAINTERESSE = 61) AS PEDAGOGIA, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CURSOS
WHERE IDAREAINTERESSE = 62) AS CONTABILIDADE FROM CURSOS) SELECT
CASE 
     WHEN DIREITO > PEDAGOGIA AND DIREITO > CONTABILIDADE THEN DIREITO
     WHEN PEDAGOGIA > DIREITO AND PEDAGOGIA > CONTABILIDADE THEN PEDAGOGIA
     WHEN CONTABILIDADE > DIREITO AND CONTABILIDADE > PEDAGOGIA THEN CONTABILIDADE
    END AS MAIOR FROM CTE
```

Consegui o resultado pelo case, Porém gostaria de um jeito mais fácil de pegar o maior valor dentro da CTE das subconsultas,visto que coloquei apenas alguns cursos, pois são muitos. Tentei fazer um union all junto com a função max() porém deu erro de subconsulta retornando mais de um valor. Teria outra forma? Agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Tente isto:

```
SELECT IDAREAINTERESSE, COUNT(*)
FROM CURSOS
GROUP BY IDAREAINTERESSE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```